# how to insert row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to insert a new row to grid view while i click **new** button with out using the sqldatasource. and also how to edit, update, and delete rows from grid view. pls help me

[visual studio 2008
asp.net with c#]

thanks 
  thiru

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "without using the SqlDataSource" ? How do you intend to propagate the inserted data to the data store, then ? You have not specified what other method you are using.

Anyway, the GridView does not inherently support insertion of records, but you can accomplish it by creating a FooterTemplate in which you create the fields for entry of new data. Additionally, provide a column to allow for Insert/Cancel buttons in the FooterTemplate.

Here's a good sample: [How to easily insert row in GridView with SqlDataSource](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-insert-row-in-GridView-with-SqlDataSource.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Good gridview tutorial : [ASP.NET Quickstart Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For adding new row you could try putting controls in footer row of the GridView.

Editing, updating and deleting require you to do two things:

1. implement those operations in the SqlDataSource
2. enable these operations in GridView

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without the SQL datasource, then set DataTable as a GridView's datasource.

[Good example on how to populate and add a row to datatable.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/AddRowtoDataTable.htm)